# IMAPI: COMException Internal file system error occurred [-1062555360 ]

Tags: c#, sandbox, imapi

I am writing CD/DVD using IMAPI with C#.NET windows application.
The data I write on CD contains one executable file (test.exe) which is also developed with C#.NET and **virtualized (sandobx) using** Turbo Virtualization Studio.
All data to be written on CD is placed in one folder (source path) on C drive.

Following is small code snippet: -

```
IStream stream = null;
try
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Adding - " + thisFileItem.SourcePath);
    if (thisFileItem.SourcePath != null)
    Win32.SHCreateStreamOnFile(thisFileItem.SourcePath, Win32.STGM_READ | Win32.STGM_SHARE_DENY_WRITE, ref stream);
    if (stream != null)
    {
        fileSystemImage.Root.AddFile(thisFileItem.DestPath + thisFileItem.DisplayName, stream);
    }
}
finally
{
    if (stream != null)
    {
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(stream);
    }
}
```

Call to "fileSystemImage.Root.AddFile" method while adding test.exe throws COMException -1062555360 "Internal file system error occurred." All other files add and write properly.

Exception Details: -

```
COMException -1062555360
Internal file system error occurred.
   at ImapiInterop.IFsiDirectoryItem.AddFile(String path, IStream fileData)
   at ImapiImplementation.CDWriter.objBackgroundWorker_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) in C:\.........\CDWriter.cs:line 405
```

If I put my source folder on some other location (Desktop or D drive), all writing process (including test.exe) happens fine without error.

I suspect the issue is due to virutalization but not sure.
Please help.

Comment: -1062555360 == 0xC0AAB120 ==  IMAPI_E_IMAGE_SIZE_LIMIT == "Adding 'filename' would result in a result image having a size larger than the current configured limit".  IMAPI of course doesn't know anything about where the file came from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message returned by IMAPI is incorrect and that is why all confusion.
Refer following link.

[social.msdn.microsoft.com](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f5531b61-53ea-4dda-8d0f-bb1f6f20c4e7/ifilesystemimage-ifsidirectoryitem-and-ierrorinfo?forum=windowsopticalplatform)

Following is the text copied from answer (from Dmitri) on above site: -

> IMAPI supports the ISupportErrorInfo interface, and we are aware of
>   the issue of mismatching error messages in your scenario.
>
> Internally, IMAPI creates rollback objects to undo add/remove file
>   actions. We've had an issue where the rollback action was created
>   prematurely, so after the return code for IFsiDirectoryItem::AddFile
>   was already set, the rollback action was to remove the file from the
>   image. Since the file hasn't been added, IMAPI_E_FSI_INTERNAL_ERROR
>   exception was thrown, which changed the IErrorInfo message to the one
>   you're seeing.
>
> We are aware of this issue, and it will be fixed in the next release
>   of IMAPI. Unfortunately, it is not serious enough to be addressed in a
>   hotfix.